# Latex: Image Is Cut Off On Left And Bottom

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a heatmap image (.png) that I want to include in the PDF my Latex generates.  Here's what it currently looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the labels on the left and bottom sides of the heatmap are partially cut off.  Any idea how to address this issue?

For reference, here's my Latex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}                                             
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% privides the H option
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\includegraphics{hm}\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you provided does not crop the image in any way. Check if the image itself isn't cropped, otherwise try to make a compilable code that cuts the image so that we can find the cause.

Comment: What do you get with command `\includegraphics[width=10cm]{hm}`?

Comment: Yes, ask in a Python-forum.  I'm assuming that is created by `matplotlib`?  `matplotlib` sometimes doesn't get the bounding box right, so axis labels are cropped off.  `fig.savefig('filename.pdf',bbox_inches='tight')`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239261/ and related questions.